# ActiveRecord #increment! returns false, but no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, increment

Here's a piece of code in my controller:

```
  @post.increment!(:views_count) # => false, record not saved, views_count is 0
  @post.errors                   # => is empty
  @post.save!                    # => true, views_count magically incremented to 1
```

The problem is, that without #save! it doesn't really work: record is not updated, views_count is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the controller code, at least the action where this is being executed, and possibly the model as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading the record? I bet that you are looking at a cached version of the file. try:

```
@post.increment!(:views_count)
@post.reload
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are using the method.

The `increment!` returns false, when the record could not be saved.

I think one possible thing you could try would be to initialize the views_count attribute to 0. I think it might currently be `nil` instead of an integer value. And on `nil` value, you can't perform `+=` operator.

To initialize value for an attribute, find the migration file for the attribute under db/migrate folder.

Modify the attribute code to something like this.

```
t.integer :views_count, default: 0
```

or if you added the column individually apart from table creation ...

```
add_column :appropriate_model, :views_count, :integer, default: 0
```

Comment: The source for the [`increment` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment) indicates that it initializes the attribute value to 0 if it's `nil`: `self[attribute] ||= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `increment!` calls `update_attribute`, which in turn calls `save(:validate => false)`. That skips validations, but [the callback chain is still executed](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save), and:

> If any of the before_* callbacks return false the action is cancelled and save returns false.

Do you have any `before_*` callbacks defined in your model that could be returning false but not setting anything in `errors`?